# Discord .js Purge Command v12(stable)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am fairly new to discord.js and am just learning as I go. I wanted to create a !purge command which will delete a specified number of messages in the chat. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `message.channel.bulkDelete()` to do this. Assuming you have your `client.on("message")` already setup such that you can separate your command from your args, the method of purging a given amount of messages is fairly simple.

Here is an example, directly taken from [my own discord bot](https://github.com/Cannicide/scav-bot/blob/495d8e10dfe927ce8028f5bda0e9ce5a142b6b54/commands/moderation.js#L102) (and therefore thoroughly tested):

```
//Mass-deletes messages
function doPurge(message, args) {
    var purgeamnt = args[0];
    var purgelimit = Number(purgeamnt) + 1;
    message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: purgelimit }).then(messages => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        message.reply("deleted " + messages.array().length + " messages, including deletion command.");
    }).catch(err => {
        message.channel.send("Failed to delete messages. This may be caused by attempting to delete messages that are over 2 weeks old.");
    });
}
```

Again, this is assuming you have created some sort of `args` variable which is an array of all of the arguments of your command. If you wanted to purge 5 messages, for example, you would do `!purge 5`. In that scenario, `"5"` should be `args[0]`. If you have an args variable setup in that fashion, you can simply call the method above (`doPurge(message, args);`) to purge the messages.

Please also note two things:

a) `bulkDelete()` will only allow you to delete messages that are newer than two weeks. There is no way to bypass this without deleting all of the messages in the channel, or without sacrificing speed and efficiency.

b) You should check the user's permissions before allowing them to use this command. Make sure they have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission or the `ADMINISTRATOR` perm, using something like `if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) doPurge(...)`.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, Can I use your unban code for getting the user id?

Comment: No problem! And sure, you can use any of my code (including the code for getting the user ID), as long as you understand how the code works instead of just directly copy-pasting!